# Data augmentation for Image Segmentation with Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I am training a neural network to predict a binary mask on mouse brain images.
For this I am augmenting my data with the ImageDataGenerator from keras.

For my purpose it is important that the network is invariant to intensity shifts in the input image, meaning that it needs to predict the same mask for the same input image even if its intensities got linearly shifted.

To teach this invariance, I want to augment my data such that for each image that is created with the keras ImageDataGenerator I have a corresponding mask that is unchanged.
Is there any way to do this?

Also I would like to apply other spatial transformations where it is important that the mask receives the same transformation as the input image.

I am currently augmenting my data with:

```
        image_datagen = kp.image.ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
        mask_datagen = kp.image.ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
        image_val_datagen = kp.image.ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
        mask_val_datagen = kp.image.ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

        image_generator = image_datagen.flow(x_train, seed=seed)
        mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(y_train, seed=seed)
        image_val_generator = image_val_datagen.flow(x_val, seed=seed + 1)
        mask_val_generator = mask_val_datagen.flow(y_val, seed=seed + 1)

        imgs = [next(image_generator) for _ in range(1000)]   
        masks = [next(mask_generator) for _ in range(1000)]
        imgs_val = [next(image_val_generator) for _ in range(1000)]
        masks_val = [next(mask_val_generator) for _ in range(1000)]

        imgs = np.concatenate(imgs)
        masks = np.concatenate(masks)
        imgs_val = np.concatenate(imgs_val)
        masks_val = np.concatenate(masks_val)
        train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(imgs), tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(masks)))
        train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat().shuffle(1000).batch(32)
        validation_set = tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(imgs_val), tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(masks_val)))
        validation_set = validation_set.repeat().shuffle(1000).batch(32)
```

Comment: "I want to augment my data such that for each image that is created with the keras ImageDataGenerator I have a corresponding mask that is unchanged" > This is already how the ImageDataGenerator works. The image is augmented but the target (here, the binary mask) stays the same. Are you looking for the built-in [brightness shift](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) (cf `brightness_range` argument of `ImageDataGenerator`)?

Comment: @asac yes I am looking for the built in brightness shift but I have to apply the transformations such that if the number of images are increased, the number of masks are increased as well.
Also spatial transformations need to be applied to both masks and images

Comment: Not sure how to do that short of applying the additional random transforms manually. Note that there is a [proposed redesign](https://github.com/keras-team/governance/blob/master/rfcs/20190729-keras-preprocessing-redesign.md) of the image processing pipeline in keras which addresses your use case. But it is not implemented yet.

Comment: Is there a way to add selfmade functions to the keras ImageDataGenerator?

Comment: also, keras seems to interpolate the data when doing a spatial transformation. This is completely unwanted when augmenting a binary mask. Is there no way to use something like nearest-neighbour?